# Управление настройками камеры через Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, камера

Известно, что при помощи Intent можно переключать режимы камеры "фото" и "видео". Но, можно ли с его помощью управлять другими настройками камеры?

Например, такими как геометки, режим съёмки и т.п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь не идет о "чистом" Андроиде, то каждый производитель пилит свое приложение "Камера". Соответственно, и возможности этих приложений отличаются. И нет никакой публичной документации по этому поводу.

Поэтому, в общем случае, ответ на ваш вопрос: нет, нельзя.

Я пробовал брать приложение "Камера" от Самсунга (дистрибутивы доступны в сети) и распаковывать его до исходников. Там есть определенный набор параметров, которые передаются через Intent. Но их немного и практически не касаются режима съемки. Дальше я разбираться не стал, т.к. смысла не увидел...

Сейчас Гугл всерьез взялся за улучшение работы с камерой и появилась возможность нормально (а не так, как это было раньше) встраивать камеру в своё приложение. И вот там уже можно управлять настройками. [Ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture).

Правда это пока Alpha и нужно перейти на AndroidX. Поэтому, в боевом проекте, пожалуй, пока что рано это использовать. Но начинать разбираться и экспериментировать можно уже сейчас.